# How to run Junit test with a specific Category defined in a POM.xml using IntelliJ

Tags: java, intellij-idea, junit

I would like to know if using IntelliJ, is possible to run all test in the visual environment choosing a specific Junit category.

At the moment if you execute:

```
mvn clean test
```

you execute **Fast** Tests, but how to use IntelliJ to choose **Slow** or **Fast**?

Fragment of **pom.xml**

```
  <profiles>
    <profile>
      <id>SlowTest</id>
      <properties>
        <testcase.groups>YOUR.PROJECT.test.categories.Slow</testcase.groups>
      </properties>
    </profile>
    <profile>
      <id>FastTest</id>
      <properties>
        <testcase.groups>YOUR.PROJECT.test.categories.Fast</testcase.groups>
      </properties>
      <activation>
        <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
      </activation>
    </profile>
  </profiles>
```

Many thanks in Advance

Juan Antonio

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your profiles are focusing the test run on specific categories. The JUnit Run/Debug configuration in IntelliJ also allows you to focus a JUnit run on a specific category.

You can access this configuration window from `Run > Edit Configurations`
Here's a screenshot showing a saved confoguiraiton named `SlowTests` which runs all tests having the category: `com.stackoverflow.surefire.SlowTests`:

[image]

You can save any such configuration by clicking on the file icon in the top left hand corner of this window and then that configuration will be available in the `Run` menu and you can [even associate a keyboard short cut with it](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9448-run-configuration-as-action).

More information [in the docs](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/run-debug-configuration-junit.html).

Comment: This is the solution! :) With this configuration, it is possible see in a visual way in the IDE the development based on Categories to see if the tests cover all cases or not. Many thanks @glitch

Answer (score 0):

If you created your project using the pom.xml, in the "Maven Projects"-View you can activate the profiles you want to be active. There (Lifecycle) you can start the goal you want to be executed for each module as well.

How to get this: View->Tool Windows->Maven Projects

Comment: Hi @aschoerk, yes using that way is possible, but I would like to see the list of test in the same way when you click right with the mouse and you click in the button "Run All Test"

Comment: But I think "Run all Tests" scans the source directory for the tests it can find there and executes them not dependent on the active profiles.

Comment: yes but if you have Mock Tests and System Tests together, the alternative that I see is to put the tests in different packages, but I would like to maintain the same package